# RabbitMq Broker not accepting PFX

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq, tls1.2

After having a working solution of `RabbitMq` over `SSL` using the certs generated by `OpenSSL`, I was given a requirement from our client that we **cannot** use `OpenSSL` to generate the certs. The server admin went and created the certificate chain via `IIS`.

We did the following to the certs after creation:

1. exported the server certs to a `PFX` and extracted **cert.pem** and **cert.key**
2. exported the client cert to a `PFX` and extracted **cert.pem** and **cert.key**
3. exported the Root CA to **rootca.pem**
4. updated the config file for `RabbitMq`

To test the connections and certificates were created properly, we went through the [Troubleshooting Steps here.](http://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html)

Everything passed fine. We are able to connect using `openssl s_client` on port `5671` as expected using the client's **cert.pem** and **cert.key** generated from **client.pfx**. We can see the connection made in management console, as well as in the logs, and they communicate back and forth.

Now, using the **client.pfx** in the .NET client, we are getting an error about the certificate validation:

> MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect failed: admin@mitvs-atm01:5671/ ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

How can I be getting an error using the **client.pfx** but not get an error when using the **cert.pem** and **cert.key** that I extracted from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing the connections through `OpenSSL` using `s_client`, it performs no or very basic verification and .NET apps can provide a function that applies any logic. The most common verification type is matching certificate's CN against server's hostname but it really can be anything.

So, even on a trusted Root CA, the CN still needs to match the hostname, which isn't picked up using `OpenSSL` commands.

Regenerating the cert and amending that fixed the problem.

Also, you could effectively add the code below and it will disregard this error:

```
h.UseSsl(s =>
{
    s.ServerName = SslHostName;
    s.CertificatePath = SslFileLocation;
    s.CertificatePassphrase = SslPassphrase;

    // The below allows the Root CA's CN to be different than the others, but adds vulnerability
    s.AllowPolicyErrors(System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch);
});
```

Please note - Ignoring errors carries the risk of exposing your system to MITM attacks (unless you implement your own verification logic that's not based on CN/hostname matching, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that client can't validate server certificate. Your problem is likely to do with **rootca.pem** not being trusted on your client's machine. Follow the appropriate OS guide to make the root CA certificate trusted.